# A more succinct way to map functions onto fields of an algebraic datatype?

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I have a datatype with lots of fields:

```
data ManyFields a b c d .. = MF { f1 :: a, f2 :: b, f3 :: c .. }
```

Problem One

How do I map function onto each field while avoiding implementing a `map` function for each one. 
For example, this looks very tedious and non-idiomatic:

```
-- | Note I am explicitly constructing ManyField after mapping a function onto the field
-- | This looks bad
mapf1 :: (a -> a1) -> ManyFields a b c ..  -> ManyFields a1 b c ..
mapf1 g mf = MF (g . f1 $ mf) (f2 mf) ..

-- | Repeat for each field
mapf2 :: (b -> b1) -> ManyFields a b c .. -> ManyFields a b1 c ...
```

I think some sort of higher-order function that abstract out the pattern of `constructor . (mapfunction f)` would cut down on the boilerplate, but is there a better solution?

Problem Two

If I want to zip many ManyFields together and map a function of arbitrary arity onto each field, does this sound like it could be an instance of some type class?

Use case:

```
(==) `mapFunction` mf1 `pairWiseZipField` mf2
```

It kind of looks like an applicative to me, but again I'm not sure how to implement `fmap` onto this type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't really do this with a standard function. The best approach is to have a map function for each field. Happily, you can generate these automatically with a bit of template haskell from the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library. It would look something like this:

```
data ManyFields a b c d = MF { _f1 :: a, _f2 :: b, _f3 :: c, _f4 :: d }

makeLenses ''ManyFields
```

This generates a *lens* for each field of `ManyFields`. The lens is a simple construct that allows you to both access *and* change the value there--the changes can even be polymorphic, just like map! Note how each field is prefixed with an underscore: the lens has the same name as the field minus the underscore.

You can now access values like this:

```
> foo = MF 'a' "b" 3 False
> foo^.f1
'a'
```

You can set values using the `set` operator. When used with a lens, it creates a setter function:

```
> :t set f1
set f1 :: a' -> ManyFields a b c d -> ManyFields a' b c d
```

To actually use it, you could do this:

```
> set f1 () foo
MF () "b" 3 False
```

Since you have a getter and a setter, writing a map function is pretty trivial. Happily, we don't even have to do this: the library provides a function called `over`:

```
> :t over f1 
over f1 :: (a -> a') -> ManyFields a b c d -> ManyFields a' b c d
```

If you like infix operators more, `set` can also be called `.~` and over can be called `%~`. (The latter has a mnemonic: `%` is mod, or "modify" :P.) This is also useful with the `&` operator which is just `$` flipped. So the following two versions are equal:

```
> over f1 ord foo
MF 97 "b" 3 False
> foo & f1 %~ ord
MF 97 "b" 3 False
```

I personally think the operators are a bit much. Unless you're going to be using lenses *everywhere*, I would stick to `set` and `over`.

I don't know of a good solution for zipping functions the way you described. But do take a look through the rest of the lens library--it's pretty large, and you never know what you'll find!

Comment: I think that's an excellent introduction to lens, which I think is the best solution to this problem.